# Detecting the direction of the accelerometer movement on the y axis

Tags: iphone, uiaccelerometer

I currently detect movement on the y axis. How does one calculate the direction it moved on the axis?

I get the same values when moving up or down.

Is the Gyro needed for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do remember that the accelerometer will reflect the force of gravity. So movement up and down will generally be reflected as 9.81 m/s<sup>2</sup> plus or minus the actual acceleration of the device relative to the Earth.

Comment: any remarks on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28959943/ios-accelerometer-values-at-any-orientation?noredirect=1#comment46172543_28959943